# SQL Query for equal and opposite values

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

Suppose I have a table with two columns `id` and `val`. I wan't to find all the distinct `id`s where there exist a pair of equal and opposite `val`s. For example suppose you have the following table

```
  id  | val
------+------
   1  |  3
   2  |  5
   2  | -5
   1  |  4
   2  |  6
   3  |  9
   2  | -6
   3  | -9
```

I want the result to be

```
result
  2
  3
```

`2` in the result set because there are values `5, -5` and `6, -6`. `3` is in the result set because of `9, -9`.

I can do this by using `where exists`. Something like

```
select distinct tab1.id from tab tab1
where exists (
    select * from tab tab2
    where tab1.id = tab2.id
    and tab1.val = -tab2.val
);
```

However I worry that a query like this has time complexity `O(n^2)` because it is computed like nested loops (?). However it is possible to compute this in `O(n)` time by scanning the table (and keeping track of previously seen results in a data structure with `O(1)` lookup time). What is the optimal way to write such a query?

Comment: Check (and post) the query plan before assuming the performance.

Comment: I don't see any nested loops here. Perhaps a bit of a cartesian product sort of situation, but nothing terrible. It looks like a nice correlated subquery which should perform similar to a INNER JOIN (which would also work in this situation)

Answer (score 0):

We should have an explain of your request and how you sets indexes.

May be it could be done like this too :

```
WITH pos AS (
  SELECT id, val FROM tab WHERE val > 0),
neg AS (
  SELECT id, val FROM tab WHERE val < 0)
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM pos JOIN neg USING (id)
 WHERE pos.val = neg.val;
```

With right indexation, this could be quick. Depend also of the volume of data.